Scrollbar not appearing inside a div in React
I'm trying to implement a vertical scrollbar in my React app within a specific div (.thelist) where tasks are displayed. Despite setting overflow-y: auto; and a fixed height, the scrollbar either doesn’t appear, or the tasks overflow the container.
Here’s the relevant code:
Below is my ListNote.js component:
function ListNote({ title, onDelete, onEdit, id }) {
  return (
    <div className="thelist">
      <div className='task-item'>
        <span className='task-name'>{title}</span>
        <div className='button-group'>
          <button onClick={() => onEdit(id)}>Edit</button>
          <button onClick={() => onDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

CSS:
.thelist {
  padding: 8px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.task-item {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center;
  background: #8758ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
  0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}

.task-name { 
  color: #fff; 
}

I also have a header containing the title that should stay fixed at the top.

The scrollbar isn't appearing because the .thelist container is wrapping each individual task instead of the entire list of tasks. This means there's no overflow within .thelist to trigger the scrollbar.
To fix this, you should move the .thelist div to wrap around all the ListNote components collectively.
Here's how you can modify your code.
Update your parent component to wrap all tasks within .thelist:
function TaskList({ tasks, onDelete, onEdit }) {
  return (
    <div className="thelist">
      {tasks.map(task => (
        <ListNote
          key={task.id}
          title={task.title}
          id={task.id}
          onDelete={onDelete}
          onEdit={onEdit}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

And your ListNote component:
function ListNote({ title, onDelete, onEdit, id }) {
  return (
    <div className='task-item'>
      <span className='task-name'>{title}</span>
      <div className='button-group'>
        <button onClick={() => onEdit(id)}>Edit</button>
        <button onClick={() => onDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

